# How do I disable the drop shadow from text on the Desktop?

Tags: finder, desktop, customization, text

Does anyone know how to get rid of the text drop shadow from files and folders on the Mac desktop?

I would prefer a subtle shadow with an offset of 1 pixel.

[image: pretty]

If you know of a hack to get rid of the drop shadow completely, please share!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Before this was edited, it looked a bit like a rant. In the future, please keep ranting out of your posts and focus on what you want to achieve. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: I'm hopeful for a command line solution or script that would serve to to decrease or drop the shadow (ie not a packaged application download).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it exists as a setting. You could go around the problem by using a black or dark background.

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment with modifying system font settings using the free utility [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html). Note that with the Fonts panel open in Tinkertool, you can specify font shadow settings.

I don't know what results you might achieve, since the Mac OS prevents you from over-riding certain settings.

[image]

You can use TinkerTool to reset any settings you change to the system default.